How can i solve this kind of error in react native?
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\subug\OneDrive\Desktop\React CLI Project\FirstProject\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\subug.gradle\caches\8.6\scripts\drznp2cu5gpd9z7oay2ucz99t).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 66


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
I run my react native project in vs code that produce this type of error how to solve this.
Give me correct solution for this error

According to the official grade docs: Java 17 and later versions are not yet supported.
You can check compatibility here.
So You have installed Java11 from Azul.
p.s. don't forget to change jdk version in Android studio which is available only on the Android project, to open it
File-> open -> select the android folder inside your react native project -> open in a new window
Then you can change jdk version Preferences -> Build -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK
